# Add quantile column for timedelta [Pandas]

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to add the mean and the quantiles for the sample table that I have added below - however, I am struggling with the quantiles. This is what I have tried so far:

```
df_grouped = df.groupby('date') \
       .agg({'delay':'count', 'delay_time':'mean'}) \
       .rename(columns={'delay':'#_delays','delay_time':'Mean_flight_delays'}) \
       .reset_index()
```

Main_df

```
date           flight_#   delay      delay_time
2019-01-01     100        1          04h:10min
2019-01-01     123        1          03h:58min
2019-01-01     121        1          04h:12min
2019-01-01     101        1          03h:45min
```

Output_df

```
date           #_delays    Mean_flight_delays   0.25_quantile.  0.50_quantile   0.75_quantile  
2019-01-01     100         4:01:15
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an option:

```
df_grouped = (df.groupby('date')
        .agg({
           'delay': 'count',
           'delay_time': [
               ('delay_mean', lambda x: x.mean()),
               ('delay_q25', lambda x: x.quantile(0.25)),
               ('delay_q50', lambda x: x.quantile(0.5)),
               ('delay_q75', lambda x: x.quantile(0.75)),
           ]})
       .droplevel(0, 1)
       .reset_index())

print(df_grouped)
```

Output:

```
         date  count      delay_mean       delay_q25       delay_q50  \
0  2019-01-01      4 0 days 04:01:15 0 days 03:54:45 0 days 04:04:00   

        delay_q75  
0 0 days 04:10:30
```

P.S. You can also set `interpolation` parameter of `quantile` to match your needs (by default it's linear, see the [doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.quantile.html))